# Python Sentence Transformer - Get matching Sentence by index order

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, sentence-transformers

I have a database table with lot of records. And I am comparing the sentence to find a best match.

lets say the table contains 4 columns: id, sentence, info, updated_date.
The data contains as below:

| id | sentence | info | updated_info_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 19/12/2022 |
| 2 | Company Name | some distinct info | 18/12/2022 |
| 3 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 17/12/2022 |
| 4 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 16/12/2022 |
| 5 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 15/12/2022 |
| 6 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 14/12/2022 |
| 7 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 13/12/2022 |
| 8 | What is the phone number of your company | some distinct info | 12/12/2022 |
| 9 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 11/12/2022 |
| 10 | What is the name of your company | some distinct info | 10/12/2022 |

I have converted these sentences to tensors.

And I am passing this as an example "What is the name of your company"(tensor) to match.

```
sentence = "What is the name of your company" # in tensor format
cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(sentence, all_sentences_tensors)[0]

top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=5) 
or
top_results = np.argpartition(cos_scores, range(5))[0:5]

top_results does not return the top results index wise.
As the sentences are same, all will have a score of "1". And it returns the results arbitrarily.
```

What I want is to get the top 5 matches with the latest updated_date order or the index order.

Is this possible to achieve ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is as follows:

1. Get the cosine similarity scores for each sentence and store them in an array.
2. Sort the array based on the updated_date
3. Get the top 5 indices from the sorted array
4. Get the corresponding sentences from the database table using the indices
5. This should give you the top 5 matches with the latest updated_date or the index order.
   Something like this should work:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Create a CountVectorizer object to transform the sentences into vectors
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

# Transform the sentences into vectors using the CountVectorizer object
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)

# Calculate the cosine similarity scores using the cosine_similarity function
cosine_scores = cosine_similarity(vectors)

# Convert the cosine similarity scores to a 1-dimensional numpy array
cosine_scores = cosine_scores.flatten()

# Sort the array of cosine similarity scores in ascending order
sorted_indices = cosine_scores.argsort()

# Get the top 5 indices from the sorted array
top_5_indices = sorted_indices[-5:]

# Get the corresponding sentences from the database table using the indices
top_5_sentences = [sentences[i] for i in top_5_indices]
```

Comment: Thank you, that logic worked:

Get the cosine similarity scores for each sentence and store them in an array.
Sort the array based on the updated_date
Get the top 5 indices from the sorted array.

Though I am using Bert & pytorch_cos_sim for similarity.